# Insert columns and the formula adjusts with it

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Lets say I have a number in cell A1 and a number in B1 and the forumla "=B1-A1" in C1.

Now I insert a column to put a new number into the newly made C1 cell and the formula has moved across to D1 but still refers to the "=B1-A1" formula.

How can I make it that each time I insert a column, the formula focus moves across too, such that after inserting a new column "C", the formula now reads "=C1-B1"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the **offset** formula in cell C1. Try this out.

```
=OFFSET(C1,0,-1,1,1)-OFFSET(C1,0,-2,1,1)
```

Comment: This is better than mine when you know exactly where the reference is. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of tricky, but to always reference the two cells to the left of the cell that the formula is in, you'll need a formula like this -

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1)-OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-2)
```

This subtracts the one two cells to the left from the one that's one cell to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting at column C, I would copy C1 to D1, then overtype C1 with the new value.

The formula in D1 will show =C1-B1.